# importing CSV to MYSQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, content-management-system

I am importing a CSV file to my admin area and I want to add files to my database. My PHP code for `import.php` is:

```
<?php 

include_once('../include/connection.php');

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

    //get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
    do {
        if ($data[0]) {
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO mobi(promo_title, promo_content, promo_image, promo_link, promo_cat, promo_name) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."'
                )
            ");
        }
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
    //

    //redirect
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die;

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  Choose your file: <br />
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The code displays correctly but when I select my test file and hit submit, I am hit with these problems:

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in admin/import.php on line 23

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in admin/import.php on line 23

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in admin/import.php on line 23

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in admin/import.php on line 23

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in admin/import.php on line 23

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in admin/import.php on line 23

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in admin/import.php on line 23

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in admin/import.php on line 23

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at admin/import.php:1) in admin/import.php on line 29
```

Can anyone see the reason?

my connection.php code is this:

```
<?php

try {
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*********', '*********', '*********');
}catch (PDOException $e){
  exit('Database Error.');
}

?>
```

please note that my other pages such as add.php, delete.php, edit.php and so on all work with the same include_once for connection.php

SO THERE IS NOTHINGWRONG WITH MY DATABASE CONNECTION.

thank you.

Comment: check your `connection.php` to correct database establish.

Comment: hi. for my connection im using this: try { $pdo = new PDO does this need to be reflected in the code above?

Comment: It seems that your database has a `password` and you leaved it blank.

Comment: where did i leave it blank? how did I leave it blank. can you point it out to me. every other file in my admin connects to this using the same include code so how am I doing something wrong with this one as it is reading the same page.

Comment: please read my updated post

Comment: check in the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `PDO` to establish a database connection. But `$pdo` instance is not used anymore!

To executes an SQL statement, need to use like `$pdo->query("INSERT INTO mobi ...")`

Instead, You are using `mysql_query` to send a MySQL query. So you get these warnings:

`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

`A link to the server could not be established`

Also make sure you are not output any strings, etc... before your `header()` function to remove this warning: `headers already sent`.

Comment: ok so I changed mysql_query with $pdo->query. and it removes all the first problems but not the last one regarding the header.

Comment: make sure there is not any space before `<?php` top of the code. If exist remove it.

Comment: Vahid Hallaji - thank you so much. this works fine. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your database credentials may be wrong.
Check if the server is accessible.

and the header information already sent is caused by the blank space before your php code

```
 <?php 

include_once('../include/connection.php');
```

with

```
<?php 

include_once('../include/connection.php');
```

Comment: Na.. there is an extra space before <?php,

Answer (score 0):

Your database credentials are incorrect.  You should also look at using the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) object oriented approach to databases and should use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) instead of addslashes.  The header error is a result of the mysql errors being thrown and ouput to the page.

Comment: hi. for my connection im using this: try {
$pdo = new PDO does this need to be reflected in the code above?

Comment: Using PDO, you would need to do something like `$pdo->query(YOURQUERY);`, but you should still check the credentials being used to make the connection to begin with.

Comment: well every other page like my add.php page works using the same include page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using php to load the file so you don't have to loop through it?

I would recommend using `require_once` instead of `include_once`. `__DIR__` is also always a good thing to have in front of your include path. That way you can say where the file is from the current file, and not the current running script.

It would look something like this:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../include/connection.php';

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

    //get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];

    mysql_query("
        LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL 
        INFILE '$file'
        REPLACE INTO TABLE mobi 
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
        ESCAPED BY '\"' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
        (promo_title, promo_content, promo_image, promo_link, promo_cat, promo_name)
        SET promo_name = TRIM(BOTH '\r' FROM promo_name);
    ");
}
```