# Importing CSV to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have gathered some information from the Internet and wrote this small script to import a CSV file into a MySQL database. I think it is correct, but it's not working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 <?php 

//connect to the database
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","testdb","testdb");
mysql_select_db("testdb",$connect); //select the table    

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

    //get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
    do {
        if ($data[0]) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO class12 (htno, subcode, subname, int_marks, ext_marks, result, credits) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."'
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."'
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."'
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."'
                    '".addslashes($data[6])."'
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."'
                )
            ");
        }
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,3000,",","'"));
    //

    //redirect
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die;

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Import a CSV File</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  Choose your file: <br />
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

If possible, someone please include the code to auto-create an SQL table with a filename (without `.csv` extension) and then importing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470359/importing-csv-to-mysql-via-php?rq=1 similar

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @Miguelo just showing me an empty page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the commas in the following lines

```
                '".addslashes($data[4])."'
                '".addslashes($data[5])."'
                '".addslashes($data[6])."'
                '".addslashes($data[7])."'`
```

I have tested the [code](http://www.johnboy.com/blog/tutorial-import-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql) it's working fine.Vote if helpful

2.May be you have put table name here.You have to write database name.

`mysql_select_db("testdb",$connect); //select the table`

Comment: actually it worked :) but still retuning an empty page.. is it possible to write some echo success message replacing `header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die;`

Comment: You can do that.Is your current filename `import.php` ?

Comment: do one thing, first make the demo of this http://www.johnboy.com/blog/tutorial-import-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql then manipulate everything slowly.Remove header location, remove `mysql_query` and put echo .Now loading the page results in printing the sql query.Copy query and run using phpMyAdmin.so that you can test yourself.

Comment: is it possible to include the code to auto-create an SQL table with filename (without .csv extension) and then importing it.

Comment: Yes. Trim the file name http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php and then create a table similar to http://www.johnboy.com/scripts/import-csv-file-with-php-mysql/contacts.sql in PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query("INSERT INTO class12 (htno, subcode, subname, int_marks, ext_marks, result, credits) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."'
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."'
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."'
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."'
                    '".addslashes($data[6])."'
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."'//I think this is extra your table has 7 col only!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please remember to outlined your source code correctly.